# The total sum of the four inputs equals 100 using yup and react-hook-form

Tags: react-hook-form, yup

After searching in various places, I couldn't find a solution. I have a schema as follows:

```
Yup.object().shape({
input1: Yup.number().required(),
input2: Yup.number().required(),
input3: Yup.number().required(),
input4: Yup.number().required()})
```

I want to ensure that the sum of the fourth inputs is 100. Has anyone encountered and resolved this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `.test` Yup operator](https://github.com/jquense/yup?tab=readme-ov-file#schematestoptions-object-schema) to test your field value to see if it meets your condition.

```js
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  sum: Yup.object({
    input1: Yup.number().required(),
    input2: Yup.number().required(),
    input3: Yup.number().required(),
    input4: Yup.number().required()
  }).test({
    test: ({ input1, input2, input3, input4 }) =>
      input1 + input2 + input3 + input4 === 100,
    message: "The sum of the fields must be equal to 100"
  })
})
```

I would recommend putting your sum fields in a separate object like `sum` to scope the error to its own parent field as opposed to `root` since RHF doesn't handle the `root` custom validation like Yup expects.

Here's [a working codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-feynman-khsgm4?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx).